# Using Inet_aton for accepting command line arguments error

Tags: c

I am trying to initialize a socket given command line arguments, argv1 is ip and argv2 is port. The port works as needed, but creating an IP address is the issue. A expect input would be ./client.out 10.5.10.20 88888
This is the client side, the server side creates the port number successfully.

```c
    // Socket information
    char ipadd[255];
    strcpy(ipadd,argv[1]);
    int portval = atoi(argv[2]);
    struct sockaddr_in server_info, client_info;
    int s_addrlen = sizeof(server_info);
    int c_addrlen = sizeof(client_info);
    memset(&server_info, 0, s_addrlen);
    memset(&client_info, 0, c_addrlen);
    server_info.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server_info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_aton(argv[1], &server_info);
    server_info.sin_port = htons(portval);
```

and I receive the warning when compiling

```c
expected ‘struct in_addr *’ but argument is of type ‘struct sockaddr_in *’
 extern int inet_aton (const char *__cp, struct in_addr *__inp) __THROW;
```

Comment: *but creating an IP address is the issue*  And just what is that issue?  Your computer reboots when you try to call `inet_aton()`?

Comment: when compiling I receive the error, or if I continue my program hangs until I exit the terminal

Comment: Your server *really* listen on `88888`?

Comment: @Mathieu No, it is just an example of what the input may be, I have a port assigned by the OS that is unique each time.

Comment: Have you tried `inet_aton(argv[1], &server_info.sin_addr);` yet? (and note that `inet_aton()` returns a success value.

Comment: @Hasturkun I tried it, and the program still continues to hang, but this compiler warning is no longer there, so I think it is a start

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me

```c
char ipadd[255];
    strcpy(ipadd,argv[1]);
    int portval = atoi(argv[2]);
    struct sockaddr_in server_info, client_info;
    int s_addrlen = sizeof(server_info);
    int c_addrlen = sizeof(client_info);
    memset(&server_info, 0, s_addrlen);
    memset(&client_info, 0, c_addrlen);
    server_info.sin_family = PF_INET;
    server_info.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    inet_aton(argv[1], &server_info.sin_addr);
    server_info.sin_port = htons(portval);
```